# Minimum size of fullscreen background image when scaling browser

Tags: css, image, background, fullscreen, scale

I am currently trying to modify a wordpress theme that has a full screen image as the homepage. Right now it scales perfectly fine with the browser, the only problem is it doesn't go smaller then the original image size. It will go larger and keep its aspect ratio but when you size down the window it doesn't go smaller then the default image size.

Here is the CSS in the theme for this part:

```
/* full screen slides */
.slides.full {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #373432;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.slides.full img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I used another way that made the image go smaller then its original size but it didn't stick to the height of the browser there was just a grey background underneath.

Is someone able to help me change the css I posted to do what I am trying to achieve? It would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: min-height:100% prevent from shrinking - just set height-100% or auto

Comment: I just tried this and it does do what I was thinking, but when i pull the width of the browser in it scales the image down but there is an empty grey area that appears below the image and fills the bottom of the browser as it gets smaller, like it doesn't stick to the bottom it just scales down into the corner.

Comment: so what do u want exactly ? shrinking with constant proportion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `max-widht: 100%` and `max-height: 100%` as well to `.slides.full img`?

It's just a wild guess. It'd be helpful to see a live example.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes I did try this and unfortunatly it didn't change anything. Here is an example of the base theme: http://themeforest.net/item/anthe-wordpress/full_screen_preview/4070793  and THIS is how I want the background to scale: http://saltsurf.com

Comment: Well, in the second one the background is scaled with Javascript. I guess you could try something similar in CSS using `calc`, but that won't work with all browsers. You could also try with putting the image in a CSS background, instead of an `img`, you can now use `background-size: cover`, there's better browser support (than for `calc`) and jQuery polyfills for IE6-8

Answer (score 0):

this will keep the right proportion for the img

```
   .slides.full img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    }
```

and changing to `height:100%` will stretch the img when resized

Comment: Thanks for your response again! When I try this way it does scale down but when I scale up now it doesn't go larger then its default size and there is just a grey background around it.

Comment: so on u scale down do you want a squished background, and on scale up you want a fitting one?

Answer (score 0):

```
 .slides.full img {
  max-width:100%; /* lower virsion of IE won't work width max-width */
  width:100%;         /* for IE */
}
```